# Overload resolution in case of templates and inheritance in unique_ptr

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

I have two classes:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};
```

And two overloaded functions:

```
void call(std::unique_ptr<Base> op)
{
    std::cout << "First overloading" << std::endl;
}

template<class F>
void call(F f) 
{
    std::cout << "Second overloading" << std::endl;
}
```

Let's call it with unique_ptr of Derived

```
call(std::make_unique<Derived>());
```

I expect calling first function, however second is called instead.
Why compiler choose generic function instead of specific one? Overload resolution does not support inheritance and polymorphism?
If so, how I can fix it and call first function?

Comment: Because `F` being deduced as the exact match `unique_ptr<Derived>` is a better fit than a totally unrelated type `unique_ptr<Base>`. What is the purpose of the generic call, anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of your overloads are valid candidates. If you remove either, the remaining one is still a valid overload. In such a case, broadly speaking, the overload that will be chosen will be the one that most closely matches the arguments provided.

You provided `std::unique_ptr<Derived>`. In the first case, it expects `std::unique_ptr<Base>`. There exists an implicit conversion from `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` to `std::unique_ptr<Base>`, so this overload is legal, but it does require a conversion.

In the second case, `F` is simply deduced to be `std::unique_ptr<Derived>`. It does not require a conversion and is a closer match to the argument provided. Therefore, it is preferred.

Edit: It seems I missed the part about a fix.

You can make the overload that accepts a `unique_ptr` a function template instead. This way, you can get an exact match with the first overload, eliminating the need for a conversion. You can use `std::enable_if` to disable that overload for `unique_ptr`s of incompatible types:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>>
call(std::unique_ptr<T>);

template<class T>
void call(T);
```

Comment: In C++20, concepts simplify the syntax:
`template<std::derived_from<Base> T> void call(std::unique_ptr<T>);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, the 2nd overload is an exact match when `T` being deduced as `std::unique_ptr<Derived>`; while the 1st overload requires an implicit conversion from `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` to `std::unique_ptr<Base>`. Then the 2nd one wins in overload resolution.

You can add apply [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

```
template<class F>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<F, std::unique_ptr<Base>>> call(F f) 
{
    std::cout << "Second overloading" << std::endl;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1sf3LkG0s6EZdQXw)